# How to Continuously Retrieve and Use the Updated Value of a Variable Inside a Loop in C++

Tags: c++, thread-safety

In C++, how can I access and use the updated value of a variable that is constantly being modified inside a loop, and then return or utilize that value by calling another function or method in a thread-safe manner?"

here is my sample code that I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

class Sample {
private:
    std::atomic<int> total_width; // Use an atomic to make it thread-safe
    std::atomic<int> n; // Use an atomic to make it thread-safe
    std::atomic<bool> stop;
    std::vector<std::string> s;

public:
    Sample() : total_width(0), n(0), stop(false) {}

    void SetSample() {
        while (!stop.load()) {
            n++;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
                if (i == 2) {
                    total_width = 1;
                } else {
                    total_width = 0;
                }
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); // Simulate some work
        }
    }

    void append(const std::string& SSS) {
        s.push_back(SSS);
    }

    int GetTotalWidth() const {
        return total_width.load();
    }

    int GetN() const {
        return n.load();
    }

    void StopUpdating() {
        stop.store(true);
    }
};

int main() {
    Sample sample;

    std::thread updaterThread(&Sample::SetSample, &sample);
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");
    sample.append("s");

    // You can now retrieve the updated total_width in a loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        std::cout << "\t" << sample.GetN() << " -> " << "Total Width: " << sample.GetTotalWidth() << std::endl;
    }

    // Stop the updater thread
    sample.StopUpdating();
    updaterThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this code is that it seems that the statement

```
if(i==2){...}
```

is not being evaluated, it always output 0 instead of 1 when the "i" is 2.

Comment: Mark the variable as `volatile`.  This prevents the compiler from optimizing the variable.  The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that the contents of the variable may change by entities external to your thread or executable (such as hardware registers).

Comment: `volatile` will not guarantee proper interthread synchronization. This is related to interthread synchronization, which is something that can't be fully explained in just one or two paragraphs on Stackoverflow; instead, refer to a good C++ textbook on this subject matter.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews One of the misconceptions is that volatile is related to multithreading it is not. It's main use is for memory mapped I/O

Comment: @OP maybe you try to explain to us what you are trying to do? Do you need to call a function for each value change? Are there timing constraints? I have the feeling you're looking for a producer consumer design but I cannot be sure.

Comment: How did you tell `if(i==2){...}` not evalutade? if you meant `std::cout << "\t" << sample.GetN() << " -> " << "Total Width: " << sample.GetTotalWidth() << std::endl;` You would need some luck to see `Total Width: 1` in the output. since `total_width` will be set 0 almost immediatly after it's been set to 1. that means most of the time, the value of `total_width` would be 0.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `volatile` is not a substitute for synchronization. It is a mistake to try to use it this way. `volatile` and multithreading are unrelated concepts in C++. This mistake is common and significant enough to have its own website : https://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.in/cxx/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically not thread-safe at all, because std::vector is not thread safe.

As for the question you've asked: I don't know what you are hoping to accomplish, but there's just no time for your code to ever see a "total_width 1": it's 0 most of the time.

You can actually get the "1" result printed if you just do something like

```
if (i == 2) {
   total_width = 1;
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
} else {
   total_width = 0;
}
```

so your other thread has a chance to actually see that result.

This does NOT make the thing thread-safe, it just explains why you're not seeing a total_width 1 in your output. Or, not usually -- it might happen, but it's not very likely.